# How to make two Application Modules share the same entity cache?

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0
I have a little problem in my application through using two AppModules that contain also same ViewObjects. So to be clear one VO is declared in two AppModules. When I commit the view by using AppModule1 and then go to another page that uses the same VO but from AppModule2, I have to commit again, even through the row is previously stored in the database.
I understood that this came because different AppModules use different entityCache for database communications.
I am asking if anyone knows any option on how to sync the entity caches from the two appmodules, or how to make them use the same entity cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration you are using each AM uses a separate connection to the DB - you can't share the cache between them.
You need to implement nested Application Modules - where one AM is inside the other.
See the documentation for more.